# Alternative way of stopping music in soundeffect instance

Tags: windows-phone-7, soundeffectinstance

I used soundeffect instance to play the background music. But I'm not able to stop the sound. I used Common class to play and stop sounds.

Is there anyway to stop music while playing using soundeffectinstance?

Comment: Also SoundEffects aren't meant to be used for playing background music.

Answer (score 1):

`SoundEffect` is fire-and forget:

> Sounds play in a "fire and forget" fashion with Play; therefore, the
>   lifetime of these sounds is managed by the framework. These sounds
>   will play once, and then stop. They cannot be looped or 3D positioned.
>   To loop a sound or apply 3D effects, call CreateInstance instead of
>   Play, or call SoundEffectInstance.Play.

You need to create a `SoundEffectInstance` instead, then you can use [SoundEffectInstance.Stop()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.stop.aspx) ?

Comment: yes, SoundEffectInstance.Stop() is not worked. Without creating SoundEffectInstance it works well.  StreamResourceInfo SoundFileInfo = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(SoundFilePath, UriKind.Relative));

                // Create the SoundEffect from the Stream
                Sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(SoundFileInfo.Stream);